How can I prevent a ground fault on one outlet from tripping a GFCI protecting a series of outlets?
I have four outlets, two outside and two in the garage. The first one in the garage is the main GFCI outlet, and the other three are protected outlets.
Due to rain and Christmas decorations, the outside outlets trip the GFCI. An electrician installed another GFCI outlet in the third on the series and told me that would prevent the outside from tripping the garage, but it's still happening.
Do I need to change how something is wired to keep all of my outlets protected but prevent the outdoors from tripping the indoors?

GFCI electronics  do not like the outside.  Why it is recommended to have the circuit protection inside the house and just a regular receptacle outside in a weather proof box.

Don't do this! Christmas lights should not routinely fault like this. The GFCI trip is a warning. So be warned. Instead of making it more convenient to live with the problem --- find it, and fix it.  If you can't find the fault, ask a new question showing your layout, your installation techniques, and with some photos to get help diagnosing this.

A couple of quick pointers: 1) Use drip loops for every connection, so water falls off the wire and not onto the plugs and sockets 2) String lights are often constructed by poking sharp contacts through flimsy wire which sometimes causes exposed contacts that might be touching your gutters or a tree or the ground.   Hard to find but you can try.

I use extension cord covers wrapped in electrical tape at every connection, and outdoor power stakes for each section. Also have outlet covers on all the external outlets. It doesn't happen often but I do have a significant amount of outdoor decorations and due to torrential rain we get, have issues with it tripping a couple of times per year. This is only a concern due to freezers in the garage losing power.

The "electrician" forgot to bypass the first GFCI and address GFCI at the second socket. And clearly he didn't test anything.   Note the on-GFCI "test" button creates a true fault local to that GFCI, but it's NOT "to ground" and thus capable of tripping an upstream GFCI.  A 3-light GFCI tester should do it, though!

More unsolicited extra work for you:  It's nice to have at least two 20A circuits to the garage and at least two more for outside.  You can get by without all that, as you are.  But it's nice.  If you're having an electrician do anything and if it doesn't involve tearing open ceilings and walls, consider adding more runs back to the breaker panel and then you can't share GFCIs anyway.   Not what you're asking I know but an option to consider while this mess is under your microscope.

Possibly your cord covers and tape are the problem.   If they are not completely water tight, in a torrential rain they will FILL with water.  An outdoor extension cord plug and socket should usually be ok in rain.  I never cover mine at all and they never trip the GFCI.

Fix the ground fault?

TL;DR Add a GFCI at #2 and Rewire
The electrician was counting on the 3rd receptacle tripping before the 1st. Theoretically that should be true, because electricity takes some time to travel between receptacles and the imbalance gets to the 3rd before it gets to the 1st. In reality, differences between GFCI devices make it impossible to predict which one will trip first, and very often they will both trip for any problem in the 3rd or 4th receptacle.
The solution is to disconnect the 3rd (and by extension the 4th) from the GFCI on the 1st receptacle. However, assuming a normal daisy-chain, that would leave the 2nd receptacle unprotected, which would violate code. Given the nature of the problem, I would:

Pigtail the existing "line" and "load" wires at GFCI/receptacle #1 and put the pigtails into the line side of that GFCI/receptacle. That removes the GFCI protection from 2 and removes the redundant GFCI protection from 3 and 4.
Replace receptacle #2 with a GFCI/receptacle. Again, pigtail the wires and use just the "line" side. That protects 2 without adding redundant protection for 3 and 4.

Assuming the wiring at 3 is correct ("line" from 2, "load" to 4) that should solve the problem.
And here is a diagram I found on do-it-yourself-help.com showing the end result:

There are ways to do this without adding a 3rd GFCI. However, they involve adding another cable and/or doing some more serious moving of things, and a decent GFCI/receptacle is around $20, maybe less, and this is almost always the easiest way to solve the problem.
And either learn how to do it yourself (unless this is a rental, because then you generally are not allowed to do this yourself) or get a different electrician. Because clearly this electrician did not know what they were doing.

If I pigtail the hot and neutral wires on outlet 2 into the line side, would that keep outlet 2 on the 1st gfci, and 3 and 4 on the 3rd?

If I understand what you're asking, No.

What I'm thinking is something like this. The top is current and the bottom is what I'm thinking. https://ibb.co/TKZN4r8

And those are electrically identical.

Given that #3 is outdoors, it might be desirable to move it indoors by swapping box #2 for one that's a size bigger (or putting a Wiremold surface box in front if the current one is buried and too hard to swap out) and putting a dead front GFCI there to protect only the outdoor receptacles.

@nobody That is a reasonable idea. However, I was looking at the least-effort way of solving the problem that was asked (how to protect everything while preventing outside problems from tripping inside receptacles). Not that I'm against frame challenges or out-of-the-box answers - they're my specialty.

At the GFCI in the garage, take the hot and neutral wires on the GFCI line and load sides and tie the hots together with a pigtail to the line side of the GFCI outlet. Do the same with the neutrals.
This will isolate the GFCI in the garage and any instance that trips the outside outlets will not cause the inside to trip. The inside outlet now does not protect the others downstream. However from your description, the others are all individually protected with their own GFCI.
You may want to do this to the other outlet in the garage and replace it with a GFCI so it does not trip from an outside source as well.
Then switch out the next outlet inline with a GFCI and wire the fourth into the load side.

I suspect the downvote was because you seem to have made a faulty assumption about the other outlets all being protected.
